# Hibernate mapping when cfg file and entity file are in different folders

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've got project with this structure:

[image]

When I'm trying to access dtb via hibernate, I get this exception:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: user/DBUser
V 02, 2013 9:17:10 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/fit] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: user/DBUser
```

Could you please show me, how should the path in my config files look like? I've tried several combinations, but I can't figure out, how to write it.

`DBUser.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="DontKnowWhatShallBeHere/DBUser" table="DBUSER">
        <id name="userId" type="int">
            <column name="USER_ID" precision="5" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="USERNAME" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdBy" type="string">
            <column name="CREATED_BY" length="20" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="createdDate" type="date">
            <column name="CREATED_DATE" length="7" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3049/test</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="DontKnowWhatShallBeHere/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: just a quick thought, have you tried placing the hbm.xml inside src/main/resources/user ... to keep it consistent

Comment: this makes things even worse...If I put it there, I get `Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: ./DBUser.hbm.xml not found` ...But you're right, that it would be good practice to have it in separate folders..

Comment: sounds to me like you had <mapping resource="DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping> instead of <mapping resource="user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping> on your hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks alright. Can you try this and see : 
    `<class name="user.DBUser" table="DBUSER">`

Comment: I was thinking, if there could not be problem in that, I'm using `Spring 3 security`. I tried your code, cleaned and builded the project, neverthless I still get some exception message. The stack is here http://pastebin.com/VSM2m9yF

Comment: How is Spring security related to how you are using hibernate in the above given context? Try the above and post back what happens.

Comment: I dunno...it was just a guess..My previous comment was edited.

Comment: My firewall doesnt let me go to the site. can you post the meaningful error message here ?

Comment: it seems to me, that I only don't have all dependencies in my `pom.xml`, that are required by `hibernate`. I'll try to fix it and if I don't succeed , I'll post here a comment :)